# primefaces p:gmap in composite component, the OverlaySelectEvent is null

Tags: google-maps, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

## Environment:

1, glassfish 3.1

2, primefaces 3.0.1

## Requirement:

1, Develop a composite component named "corpInfoMap", which shows the locations of corporations in google map as "markers". when user click a marker, display the corporation's infomation in mapInfoWindow.

2, Develop an other composite component named "corpInfoMapDialog", which is a p:dialog contains the "corpInfoMap".

## Problem:

**The Map works excellent, both in page or in dialog. but when user click the marker in map:**

**The "OverlaySelectEvent"(event) which is passed into the listener method is NULL. So "event.getgetOverlay()" throws NullPonterException.**

## Code:

### 1 corpInfoMap.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" 
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
>
<cc:interface displayName="单位地理信息">
    <cc:attribute name="mapModel" required="true" displayName="地理信息Model,com.ui.fwjg.viewModel.CorporationMapModel类型" />
    <cc:attribute name="selectedListener" required="true" method-signature="void method(org.primefaces.event.map.OverlaySelectEvent)" displayName="选择锚点的方法" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
    <p:gmap zoom="#{cc.attrs.mapModel.zoom}" 
            type="HYBRID" 
            center="#{cc.attrs.mapModel.centerWd},#{cc.attrs.mapModel.centerJd}" 
            style="width:#{cc.attrs.mapModel.width}px;height:#{cc.attrs.mapModel.height}px;"
            model="#{cc.attrs.mapModel.model}"
            >
        <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{cc.attrs.selectedListener}"></p:ajax>
         <p:gmapInfoWindow rendered="#{cc.attrs.mapModel.selectedMarker != null}" maxWidth="#{cc.attrs.mapModel.width / 2}">
            <p:outputPanel style="text-align:center;display:block;margin:auto:" rendered="#{cc.attrs.mapModel.selectedMarker != null}">
                <h:panelGroup style="width:100%;font-size:1.5em;line-height:2em;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">
                    #{cc.attrs.mapModel.selectedMarker.data.dwmc}
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="com-ui-clearboth"></h:panelGroup>
                <h:graphicImage rendered="#{not empty cc.attrs.mapModel.selectedMarker.data.dwsltFile}" 
                                style="max-width:#{cc.attrs.mapModel.width / 2};display:block;margin:20px auto;" 
                                url="/file.ui?f=#{cc.attrs.mapModel.selectedMarker.data.dwsltFile}"></h:graphicImage> 
                <h:outputText value="#{mapBean.marker.title}" />
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="com-ui-clearboth"></h:panelGroup>
                <h:outputText rendered="#{not empty cc.attrs.mapModel.selectedMarker.dwjj}" 
                                value="&lt;p style=&quot;font-size:1em;line-height:1.5em;text-indent:2em;&quot;&gt;"
                                escape="false"></h:outputText>
                    <h:outputText rendered="#{not empty cc.attrs.mapModel.selectedMarker.dwjj}" value="#{cc.attrs.mapModel.selectedMarker.dwjj}">
                    </h:outputText>
                <h:outputText rendered="#{not empty cc.attrs.mapModel.selectedMarker.dwjj}" value="&lt;/p&gt;" escape="false"></h:outputText>
            </p:outputPanel> 
        </p:gmapInfoWindow>  
    </p:gmap>
    </f:view>
</cc:implementation>
```

### 2 corpInfoMapDialog.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" 
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:comuicommon="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/ui/common">
<!-- INTERFACE -->
<cc:interface displayName="单位地理信息窗口">
    <cc:attribute name="mapModel" required="true" displayName="地理信息Model,com.ui.fwjg.viewModel.CorporationMapModel类型" />
    <cc:attribute name="selectedListener" required="true" method-signature="void method(javax.faces.component.behavior.AjaxBehavior)" displayName="选择锚点的方法" />
    <cc:attribute name="dialogId" default="corpInfoMapDialog" displayName="对话框的ID" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <p:dialog header="单位地理信息" widgetVar="#{cc.attrs.dialogId}" id="#{cc.attrs.dialogId}" width="#{cc.attrs.mapModel.width}">
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{cc.attrs.mapModel != null and cc.attrs.mapModel.model != null and (not empty cc.attrs.mapModel.model.markers)}" layout="block">
            <comuicommon:corpInfoMap mapModel="#{cc.attrs.mapModel}" selectedListener="#{cc.attrs.selectedListener}"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not (cc.attrs.mapModel != null and cc.attrs.mapModel.model != null and (not empty cc.attrs.mapModel.model.markers))}" 
                    layout="block" style="font-size:2em;text-align:center;">
            该单位无地理信息。
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p:dialog>
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

### 3 The Backing Beans(One of them):

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class JlltWssbDjjsbEditPage  implements Serializable{

    ... // a lot of lines
    private CorporationMapModel corporationMapModel;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        corporationMapModel = new CorporationMapModel();
        ... // other codes, have no business with corporationMapModel.
    }

    // the OverlaySelectEvent listener method
    // when user click the marker in map, this method is invoked, but the parameter "evnet" is null.
    public void setSelectedMarker(OverlaySelectEvent event){
        corporationMapModel.onMarkerSelect(event);
    }

    public CorporationMapModel getCorporationMapModel() {
        return corporationMapModel;
    }

    public void setCorporationMapModel(CorporationMapModel corporationMapModel) {
        this.corporationMapModel = corporationMapModel;
    }

    // reset the jsb, reset the corporationMapModel's properties(only it's properties, neither it nor the mapModel in it.)
    public void setJsb(JlltWssbDjjsb jsb) {
        this.jsb = jsb;
        Corporation corporation = jsb == null ? null : (jsb.getWineInfo() == null ? null : jsb.getWineInfo().getCorporation());
        corporationMapModel.resetModel(corporation);
        setShowHistory(jsb != null);
        initWineInfo();
    }

    ... // a lot of lines, have no business with 
}
```

### 4 CorporationMapModel.java

```
public class CorporationMapModel implements Serializable{
    private List<Corporation> corporations; // 企业列表 corporation list
    private MapModel model; // 地理信息Model primefaces map model
    private String centerJd; // 地图中间位置-经度 lng
    private String centerWd; // 地图中间位置-维度 lat
    private String zoom; // 地图缩放级别 gmap zoom
    private Marker selectedMarker; // 被选择的Marker selected marker(overlay)
    private int width = 600; // the width(px) of the map
    private int height = 480; // the height(px) of the map 

    public void resetModel(Corporation corporation) {
        List<Corporation> corporations = new ArrayList<Corporation>();
        if(corporation != null){
            corporations.add(corporation);
        }
        setCorporations(corporations);
    }
    public void resetModel(List<Corporation> corporations) {
        corporations = corporations == null ? new ArrayList<Corporation>() : corporations;
        setCorporations(corporations);
    }

    private void calInfosByCorporations() {
        if(model == null)
            model = new DefaultMapModel();
        model.getMarkers().clear();
        if (corporations != null && corporations.size() > 0) {
            for (Corporation corporation : corporations) {
                CorporationMapInfo mapInfo = CorporationMapInfo.generateNewCorporationMapInfo(corporation);
                if (mapInfo != null) {
                    model.addOverlay(mapInfo);
                }
            }
            List<Marker> markers = model.getMarkers();
            if (markers != null && markers.size() > 0) {
                double maxWd = 0D;
                double minWd = 0D;
                double maxJd = 0D;
                double minJd = 0D;
                for (int i = 0; i < markers.size(); i++) {
                    Marker marker = markers.get(i);
                    if (i == 0) {
                        maxWd = marker.getLatlng().getLat();
                        minWd = marker.getLatlng().getLat();
                        maxJd = marker.getLatlng().getLng();
                        minJd = marker.getLatlng().getLng();
                    } else {
                        double wd = marker.getLatlng().getLat();
                        double jd = marker.getLatlng().getLng();
                        maxWd = maxWd < wd ? wd : maxWd;
                        maxJd = maxJd < jd ? jd : maxJd;
                        minWd = minWd > wd ? wd : minWd;
                        minJd = minJd > jd ? jd : minJd;
                    }
                }
                BigDecimal centerWd = new BigDecimal((maxWd + minWd) / 2D);
                BigDecimal centerJd = new BigDecimal((maxJd + minJd) / 2D);
                centerWd = centerWd.setScale(6, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
                centerJd = centerJd.setScale(6, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
                setCenterWd(centerWd.toPlainString());
                setCenterJd(centerJd.toPlainString());
                zoom = GoogleMapZoom.getZoom(maxWd, minWd, maxJd, minJd, width, height);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onMarkerSelect(OverlaySelectEvent event) {
        selectedMarker = (Marker) event.getOverlay();
    }

    public List<Corporation> getCorporations() {
        return corporations;
    }

    public void setCorporations(List<Corporation> corporations) {
        corporations = corporations == null ? new ArrayList<Corporation>() : corporations;
        this.corporations = corporations;
        calInfosByCorporations();
    }

    public MapModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public String getCenterJd() {
        return centerJd;
    }

    public void setCenterJd(String centerJd) {
        this.centerJd = centerJd;
    }

    public String getCenterWd() {
        return centerWd;
    }

    public void setCenterWd(String centerWd) {
        this.centerWd = centerWd;
    }

    public String getZoom() {
        return zoom;
    }

    public void setZoom(String zoom) {
        this.zoom = zoom;
    }

    public Marker getSelectedMarker() {
        return selectedMarker;
    }
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
    public void setModel(MapModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public void setSelectedMarker(Marker selectedMarker) {
        this.selectedMarker = selectedMarker;
    }
}
```

### 5 js.xhtml("js" means "reduce", not "javascript"), the important part in this xhtml file:

```
<h:form id="dwMapForm">
            <comuicommon:corpInfoMapDialog
                mapModel="#{jlltWssbDjjsbEditPage.corporationMapModel}"
                selectedListener="#{jlltWssbDjjsbEditPage.setSelectedMarker(org.primefaces.event.map.OverlaySelectEvent)}"
                dialogId="dwMapDialog"
            />
</h:form>
```

## what I've done:

1, I've googled a lot, but there are no answers.

2, I've debuged, I found that the event object has been generated by primefaces (at least, in the method of AjaxBehaviorRenderer.decode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, ClientBehavior behavior), the event object is exists, not null.)

3, and in the method of JlltWssbDjjsbEditPage.setSelectedMarker(OverlaySelectEvent event), the event is null.

## Thank you every one!

I hope I've make it clear.

## Best regards!